# Get Windows To Remember Recent Admin Auth?

Tags: administrator, sudo

Ubuntu remembers one has recently authorized admin access (Sudo and Gksu at least) to avoid the need to repeatedly auth.

Is this possible in Windows?

Comment: Do you mean disabling UAC? What version of windows.

Comment: @soandos: Disabling UAC is a bad thing to do, it breaks applications as their visualized locations are no longer accessed. It also introduces a large security risk at no benefit; if you really want to disable UAC, change the behavior of the elevation prompt for standard users to automatically approve.

Comment: I just want to understand the question.

Comment: @soandos: But it wouldn't have been a solution, I think. Please note to use [@-replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) so that people see your replies... :)

Comment: @Tom, I thought that the person directly above gets notified anyway?

Comment: @soandos: By default only the post owner gets notified, I saw your comment here because you answered on my question. Else, I would've never saw your comment unless I passed by occasionally in the future.

Comment: @soandos, I don't want to disable UAC permanently. Rather I'd prefer that successful authorization be remembered for a period of time to allow completing similar tasks without having to reenter the password again and again.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up two accounts, an administrator account and an user account.

Then, change the [Local Group Policy Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731745.aspx) such that the administrator doesn't need approval.

[image]

Comment: Then just hit CTRL+ALT+DEL to go to Fast User Switching.  This also defeats UAC dialog spoofing.

Comment: Separate accounts and user switching seem like a lot of work since it'd mean separate folders for downloads, documents, etc.

Comment: @user497816: You can create an account in under a minute; fast user switching is not needed, you can instead elevate the process to be used as the administrator.